# Can't Login To Corporate Network Via Citrix Receiver

Tags: java, citrix

So I am trying to login in to my corporate network using my MAC running OSX 10.8.5 via Citrix Receiver. I have previously been able to login with no issues, but for some reason I am now getting the following errors:

```
java.io.IOException: *** Error in initialising/invoking connection model class
at com.citrix.client.io.net.ip.w.d(Unknown Source)
at com.citrix.client.io.net.ip.proxy.o.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.citrix.client.io.net.ip.o.a(Unknown Source)
at com.citrix.client.io.net.ip.z.a(Unknown Source)
at com.citrix.client.module.td.tcp.TCPTransportDriver.s(Unknown Source)
at com.citrix.client.module.td.TransportDriver.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.citrix.sdk.jsse.d.a(Unknown Source)
at com.citrix.sdk.jsse.d.<init>(Unknown Source)
... 11 more
```

If anyone has any hints or help please let me know. I have installed the latest version of Citrix Receiver and Java Runtime Environment.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Installing Chrome sorted it!

Cheers